# question about tkinter, annualInterestRate is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I need some help with my code, my assignment is to calculate monthly payment, and total payment with a given interest. The user enters a loan amount and years. The program then displays the payments in a window using tkinter until the interest reaches 8.0.

My problem is that I can't get my program to display the interest, it only displays 0.0 but gives me the error "annualInterestRate is not defined", the program displays the monthly and total payment just fine but only the first line and doesn't continue showing the rest of the payments.

I'm really new to programming so any tips are appreciated.

Here's a link to the full file: https://pastebin.com/AUicQzu0

```
def Calculate(self):
    monthlyPayment = self.getMonthlyPayment(
        float(self.loanamountVar.get()),
        int(self.yearsVar.get()),
        float(self.annualInterestRateVar.get()))

    self.monthlyPaymentVar.set(format(monthlyPayment, '10.2f'))
    totalPayment = float(self.monthlyPaymentVar.get()) * 12 * int(self.yearsVar.get())
    self.totalPaymentVar.set(format(totalPayment, '10.2f'))
    self.annualInterestRateVar.set(annualInterestRate)

def getMonthlyPayment(self, loanamount, years, annualInterestRate):

    annualInterestRate = 5.0
    while annualInterestRate <= 8.0:
        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200
        monthlyPayment = loanamount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate) ** (years * 12))
        annualInterestRate += 1.0 / 8
        return monthlyPayment
```

Comment: The error seems to be telling the truth: inside `Calculate` you haven't defined a variable named `annualInterestrate`. What value do you think it should have?

Comment: I don't quite understand the `self.annualInterestRateVar.get()` bit. There is nowhere to put that information into your GUI. Shouldn't it just be a normal variable and not a `tkinter.DoubleVar()`?

Comment: set(), setatrr(), getattr() build-in functions.

Comment: Change to `self.annualInterestRate = 5.0`, this makes the variable a `class member`.

Answer (score 0):

In last line in `Calculate` you try to get value from variable `annualInterestRate` and assign to `self.annualInterestRateVar`

```
self.annualInterestRateVar.set(annualInterestRate)
```

But `annualInterestRate` is local variable which exists only in `Calculate` and has nothing to do with local variable `annualInterestRate` which exists in `getMonthlyPayment`

So you try to get value from variable `annualInterestRate` but you didn't assign any value to `annualInterestRate` in `Calculate`.

For Python you try to get value from variable which you never created. So Python display

```
 annualInterestRate is not defined
```

I don't know what value you try to assing in `self.annualInterestRateVar.set(...)`. If it is value from local variable `annualInterestRate` which exists in `getMonthlyPayment` then maybe you should return it from `getMonthlyPayment`

```
return monthlyPayment, annualInterestRate
```

and assing in `Calculate`

```
monthlyPayment, annualInterestRate = self.getMonthlyPayment(...)
```

---

BTW: you have wrong indention in `while` loop in `getMonthlyPayment` and it will exit `getMonthlyPayment` after first loop.